# Posting a comment on YouTube

Tags: internet-explorer, post, button, youtube, autoit

My AutoIt script should post a comment on a YouTube video. This is what I have so far:

```
$mIE=_IECreate("www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx")
$oForm=_IEGetObjByName($mIE,"comment")
_IEAction($oForm, "focus")
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
$oSubmit=_IEGetObjByName($mIE,"add_comment")
_IEFormElementSetValue($oForm,"Thanks")
_IEAction($oSubmit,"click")
```

But the script is not clicking the button "Post".

Comment: Why is it so urgent? It needs a YouTube account to test your code and most people here are helping out in their free time. So please be patient and try to rule out some mistakes in the meantime... Can you confirm, that the `$oSubmit` is the correct element? Have you tried, moving to mouse to its screen position to confirm that? You can probably use `_IEPropertyGet($oSubmit, "screenx")` to get its position (same with `screeny`) and then use a simple `MouseClick("primary", $x, $y)`. Be creative. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can submit form directly. No need to use button.

```
_IEFormSubmit($oForm)
```

If still you want to use button, make sure you are on the right button.
Change its value to "something", and see if "something" is showing on the button

```
$oButton.value = "Bla Bla"
```